# Retrieve file contents during Gatsby build

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I need to pull in the contents of a program source file for display in a page generated by Gatsby.  I've got everything wired up to the point where I should be able to call

```
// my-fancy-template.tsx
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
// ...
const fileContents = readFileSync("./my/relative/file/path.cs");
```

However, on running either `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`, I'm getting the following error

This dependency was not found:
⠀
* fs in ./src/templates/my-fancy-template.tsx
⠀
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs

However, [all the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) would suggest that this module is native to Node *unless* it is being run on the browser.  I'm not overly familiar with Node yet, but given that `gatsby build` also fails (this command does not even start a local server), I'd be a little surprised if this was the problem.

I even tried this from a new test site (`gatsby new test`) to the same effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106353/1443496) in the sidebar and gave that a shot, but it appears it just *declared* that `fs` was available; it didn't actually provide `fs`.

It then struck me that while Gatsby creates the pages at build-time, it may not *render* those pages until they're needed.  This may be a faulty assessment, but it ultimately led to the solution I needed:

1. You'll need to add the file contents to a field on `File` (assuming you're using `gatsby-source-filesystem`) during `exports.onCreateNode` in `gatsby-node.js`.  You can do this via the usual means:

   ```
   if (node.internal.type === `File`) {
       fs.readFile(node.absolutePath, undefined, (_err, buf) => {
           createNodeField({ node, name: `contents`, value: buf.toString()});
       });
   }
   ```
2. You can then access this field in your query inside `my-fancy-template.tsx`:

   ```
   { 
     allFile {
       nodes {
         fields { content }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

From there, you're free to use `fields.content` inside each element of `allFile.nodes`.  (This of course also applies to `file` query methods.)

Naturally, I'd be ecstatic if someone has a more elegant solution :-)

Comment: great answer, fs is indeed available at gatsby-node.js level !!!